# Why take RMS velocity?

Tags: kinetic-theory

Why do we consider RMS speed of gases in various calculations?
For example, I have to find the time for two successive collisions to occur for a hydrogen molecule.I get the answer if i calculate using RMS velocity.But why take it? As i know the speed of the molecule is different from RMS speed .

Answer (score 1):

Let us look at average velocity ($v_{avg}$) for a system of gas particles first.

Gas particles move around randomly in every possible direction. This means that for every particle directed a certain way, there is another particle directed to the exact opposite direction. Now, because velocity is a vector, the two of these cancel each other out. Therefore $v_{avg}=0$. Now, this is not very useful if you want to study the motion of the gas particles.

This is why the rms speed is used. The rms velocity is always non zero because it is the square root of the mean of the squares of all the quantities. This can only be a positive quantity. (This, generally, is the way to calculate rms for a distribution with distinct elements. For continuous distributions, rms is defined this way: http://www3.ul.ie/~mlc/support/Loughborough%20website/chap15/15_6.pdf )

Comment: There is actually a deeper matter---a reason why $\langle |v| \rangle$ is not only harder to actually compute with but not as correct as $v_{RMS}$---and it has to do with equipartition.

Comment: would you like to add about most probable speed

Comment: I wasn't aware of this @dmckee , could you possibly send me some links so I could read up on it?

Comment: The short version of dmckee's point, if I may, is this: In terms of statistical mechanics, it's the energy of a state that matters in determining how likely it is at a given temperature. So the *square* of the velocity (which is what goes into the kinetic energy formula) ends up being the important quantity. So $v_{RMS}$ ends up being the relevant effective average speed for most purposes when you're talking about thermodynamics.